# Maximo Anywhere Data Synchronization

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am trying to understand the implementation of Maximo Anywhere data synchronization. I could not get these details on Knowledge Center.

i. Does the framework synchronize delta changes that happen at client side, or whole object

ii. In case of nested object structures, does parent and child objects synched as one transaction or individually?

iii. If nested objects are synchronized separately, do we end up in situations which can compromise the transactional integrity and why not?

iv. We have similar conflicting scenario with the data created at client in offline mode. Considering an Object Structure consisting of parent and child, where data of both parent and child changes, what is the order of synchronization followed by the framework?

Answer (score 0):

The framework only sends the delta from the client side.

For part 2, the child objects are sent along with the main transaction updates.